# Autofit columns error when running in protected Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

When I'm execute the code its show [ Run-time error '1004': AutoFit method of Range class failed ] in protected sheet

```
Columns("D:DD").AutoFit
```

Can you guys explain to me why? and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling `UserInterfaceOnly` when you set your password will allow you to modify the worksheet using the VBA without having to unprotect the worksheet.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thomas Inzina.
you're correct just put at the top then the code is running without error. May I know why this error happen?

Comment: Sorry, I misread you last comment on the phone.  `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` allows VBA editing of locked cells on protected worksheet.  It's a safe guard.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm new here so need to study a lot of excel macro and this websites

Comment: You should watch Excel VBA Introduction[](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) on Youtube.

Comment: Where should this line be put ?